# Want to Update iMovie, etc. on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update

I have updates of iMovie, etc. on my MacBook Pro. But every time I go to update it tells me to sign into one of my email addresses first. I press OK and nothing happens. I sign into the email and there is no mail in there. Where do I sign in? I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that you have the latest version already. The latest iMovie version is 9.0.9 (1795). It prompts you to sign in to check if there are any newer versions. Since it finds nothing, it updates nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your OS, and how you obtained iMovie (for example, since you cited it in your post), you will either receive updates through the Software Update selection from the main Apple menu, or you will get them through the App Store. The latter method requires you to log in with your Apple ID. Presuming that you have a valid Apple ID, you shouldn't be required to interact with your email at all.